# Starting JavaScript query in IE from VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to develop a macro that will be able to automatically check the format of tracking number in a sheet, decide which courier site to use, and then get the status of shipment. Until now it's going pretty well, since both tnt and dhl's results have tracking no in it's address, but I got kinda stuck with ups, where the submission of form seems to be done via javascript.

I managed to trick it by focusing on input box and making my macro send keys tab, tab and enter after inputting no, but it's not so elegant and the success rate seems to be about 70% from my testing.

I tried all different variations of getelementsby..., but nothing really seemed to submit the form successfully.

Is there a way to call the JavaScript to start query, or maybe another way of submitting the form itself?

Added an edited chunk of code for testing as well as html for both what seems to be code for the button and for the JavaScript :

```
sub ups()
 Dim objIE
 Dim Website
 Dim Element
 Dim cRng As Range
 Set cRng = "1Z30RY119130505965"

 Set objIE = "https://www.ups.com/tracking/tracking.html"

 With objIE
  .visible = True
  .navigate Website

  Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4
   DoEvents
   Loop

  Set Element = .Document.GetElementsByName("trackNums")

   'a part of code I found useful for when previous Do
   'While fails and events start executing too early

   Dim btimer As Integer
   btimer = 0

   Do While Element.Item(3).Value = 0
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    btimer = 4 Then
     Exit Do
    End If
   Loop

   Element.Item(3).Focus
   Element.Item(3).Value = cRng.Value

   SendKeys "{TAB}"
   SendKeys "{TAB}"
   SendKeys "{~}"





<div class="btnBar">
<input name="track.x" class="ups-cta ups-cta_primary" type="submit" value="Track"></input>
</div>






<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript">

$(function)
{
Tracking.setLocaleString('en_KR');
Tracking.setLoadingText('Loading. Please wait a moment.');
Tracking.setErrorMessage3('The systen is unable to process your request at this time. Please try again later.');
Tracking.addInatructionTextForyinputPage("Enter up to 25 tracking or InfoNotice numbers, one per line.", 'y');
```

Thanks for any ideas in advance.